# Eclipse Java code Format

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not that much aware of Eclipse Shortcuts.

I copied code from some link and I pasted in Eclipse Indigo but it is coming like

```
"public String doLogin() throws ApplicationException{ long  executionStartTime = System.cu... }"
```

I want to format it in java style like

```
public String doLogin() throws ApplicationException{ 
    long  executionStartTime = System.cu... 
}
```

I google it and found few shortcuts like,

"Shift + Tab" , "Ctrl + I", "Ctrl + Shift + F". but is not giving me the behavior I want.

is there I need to add custom formatter or I am expecting more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With default key mapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> should format your code (current class or selection if any). Of course syntax has to be valid.

You should be able to access that feature using the menu `Source > Format` where shortcut is displayed if existing.

Comment: You are correct, I had mapping as well present, but somewhere my key was not working. when I tried "Source > Format" it gave me needed behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You can format text using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> shortcuts.

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all text or you can format only several lines (which you have selected).

There is a caveat however: If your code does not compile the formatting does not work. I don't know whether this is intentional or a bug.

You may want to enable auto-formatting in Eclipse it is a handy feature I usually use:

[image]

You can find the formatter settings here:

[image]

I also recommend the ***Eclipse Color Theme*** plugin!

Answer (score 1):

Type Ctrl+Shift+L to get list of shortcuts in Eclipse.... and to format Ctrl+Shift+F

[image: type Ctrl+Shift+L to get the list of shortcuts]

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own formatter:

`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Formatter`.

Answer (score 0):

"Ctrl + Shift + F" should work but make sure you remove " from start and end of the code you copied.

Answer (score 0):

select all text using `ctrl + a`

and press

```
Ctrl + Shift + F
```

to format text